# vector<string> msg {} not buildingfor C++ in VS Code on Mac

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to configure VS Code on a Mac (Intel) to develop with C++. I'm following the setup on the VS Code web site. Following all of the steps when I get to the Terminal - Run Build Task the build fails and indicates the it expected a ";" after 'msg'. I can run the same file in XCode with no issues, but VS Code fails. Here's the full code from the VS Code Setup site.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: initializing `std::vector` with initializer list is supported from `c++11` on-wards. Does your compile support `c++11` or later?

Comment: fails how? What is the error message?

Comment: All the error message says is that it expects a " ; " after msg.

Comment: @Harry this is a 2019 MBA and the version for clang++ says:
clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66680147/how-to-change-c-version-being-used-by-vscode

Answer (score 2):

I, too, had this same problem/error message with the same source code using my Mac Studio with M1 based on Apple arm64 silicon.

First, the source code comes from a tutorial: [Using Clang in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac).

When I run the code, I get this error for `vector<string> msg`:

```
expected ';' at end of declaration 
range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
```

Second, as @Harry [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65494537/vectorstring-msg-not-buildingfor-c-in-vs-code-on-mac#comment115791633_65494537) for this question:

> initializing std::vector with initializer list is supported from c++11 on-wards.

Solution: add a compiler version to `tasks.json` that supports `vector<string> msg`. For me, I used `-std=c++17` to the "args" list to solve the problem.  As an FYI, I verified that `-std=c++11` also solves the problem. Even `-std=c++2b` for the 2023 standard works with the Xcode version 14.2 command line extensions.

So, the default `tasks.json` file created for me in the tutorial from code.visualstudio.com was missing any reference to a compiler version directive.

Here is my updated `tasks.json` file with the one new element added to the args list:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-std=c++17",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```