# How can I change the version of the C++ language standard used in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I printed the value of the `__cplusplus` macro and found out that my files are executed with C++98 in Visual Studio Code. I'm using the CodeRunner extension.

How do I change this to C++17?

Comment: You need to update your `tasks.json` and your `c_cpp_properties.json`. The `tasks.json` configures how your compiler builds your code. The `c_cpp_properties.json` configures intellisense in the editor. You also may need to upgrade your compiler. If you are on MS Windows  and are using mingw, you may want to use the msys2 version which gives you the latest compiler and allows for easy install and upgrading and also has support for many  libraries

Comment: @drescherjm and how do I have to update them?

Comment: The files are covered in the Microsoft Documentation provided  you know your compiler command line switches: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: The tasks.json is used for the ctrl-B key.  I don't know if it's used at all by the coderunner extension, since that has to build the command dynamically depending on the currently active source file.

Comment: You didn't say what platform you're on nor which compiler you're using.  But, in a terminal window in VSCode, run the compiler command directly to see which compiler it found on the paths; e.g. `g++ --version`.  Make sure the paths are set for the desired compiler, before running VSCODE.

Answer (score 34):

Go to extensions, then type `ms-vscode.cpptools` in the search bar.

Click on the `C/C++` extension, and to the right of `Uninstall`, there should be a gear icon. Click it.

A dropdown menu should open. Select `Extension Settings`.

Now click in the search bar (sometimes it makes you click twice before you can type without replacing the extension filter) and type  `cppStandard`.

From here, you should see two options, one for Cpp Standard, and one for C Standard.

Change Cpp Standard to your desired version. I generally use c++20.

[image]

Comment: If vscode intellisense still cannot detect the standard higher than C++14. Try to search in command palette (ctrl+p or ctrl+shift+p) with `C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)`. Then check the `C++ standard` in this UI. I found it was set to `C++14` while `ms-vscode.cpptools` was set to `C++20`.

Comment: I have selected C++23 everywhere but still the code is executing in C++17. Please help! I want to use C++23.

Comment: @BittuJoshi you probably have a custom configuration file set under .vscode assuming you're building it through the vscode build process.

Answer (score 12):

Also, make sure your debugger is using the same version. In task.json the line after `--std` defines the version.

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "--std",
                "c++20",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using [the cpptools extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools) without CMake support, then use the [`C_Cpp.default.cppStandard`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference#_configuration-properties) setting, or the corresponding property of a specific configuration in your `c_cpp_properties.json`. Note that this is only for IntelliSense and does not affect the language standard used for the actual build.

If you're using CMake support from [the CMake Tools extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools) (`"configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"`), then adjust your CMake configuration in whichever way is the most suitable for your project (Ex. [`target_compile_features`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html), [`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html)).

Also, if you're using a build task to do the compilation (for the cpptools with no CMake Tools setup, IntelliSense and build configuration are separate), make sure to add the corresponding compile flag to use that C++ standard (see also [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75679583/11107541)). Not using the same language standard for build and IntelliSense is a recipe for confusion, errors, and possibly bugs.

If you're using [the clangd extension](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd), that goes off of a compile commands database (`compile_commands.json` file), which you can get automatically from CMake using [`CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html) (see also [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76214731/11107541)).

If you're using VS Code's Code Runner extension (I don't recommend this), see [How can I change the C++ standard used by the Code Runner extension for VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75892388/11107541) (edit the workspace .vscode/settings.json's [`code-runner.executorMap`](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner#configuration) setting).

Comment: Lots of options available depending on how you're using VSCode which provides lots of alternatives (because that's the nature of C++ development).  Thanks for going over the list of them!