# C++ VS Code not recognizing syntax, unable to run code

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, c++17

I am using a specific syntax needed for a course, but when I use this C++ syntax in VS Code, it doesn't work and raises errors.

Here is an example of the syntax that is not working:

```
error: expected ';' at end of declaration
        int i {0}; 
             ^
             ;
```

When I change it to `int i = 0;` the error disappears.

It specifically doesn't recognize the `{}` syntax for setting default variable values. I am using a `ssh` login for this course and the syntax works well in the `ssh`, but won't work in VS Code.

I attempted to change my VS Code C++ version to C++17 [by doing the top answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66680147/), but it still doesn't recognize the syntax.

Am I using incorrect syntax, or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The syntax is fine, you are likely just not telling the compiler to use C++11 or later correctly (what does `__cplusplus` report in the code?).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm a bit new to C++, can you explain how I can run/use that command? Do I just write it in the code and compile+run it? Do I execute the command in Terminal?

Comment: @RemyLebeau When I `cout << __cplusplus;`, it outputs: `199711`. When I hover over `__cplusplus` in VS Code with my mouse, it shows `#define __cplusplus 201703L
Expands to:

201703L`

Comment: Then clearly you are compiling in C++98 mode, which is why the syntax does not work, since C++98 predates C++11. VS Code is an editor, not a compiler. Which exact compiler are you using with it? Which exact settings did you change to try to enable C++11 or later? Be specific.

Comment: My guess is macOS (since the compiler defaults to c++98). The VSCode documentation explains the 2 places the standard needs to be set here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)

Comment: @drescherjm This helped a lot and I was able to solve the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding on to the comment above, this is what solved my issue:

Go to this link:  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac

Go to the section **Clang on macOS** and scroll down to **Troubleshooting**. Follow the steps in this paragraph:

*"If you see build errors mentioning "C++11 extensions", you may not have updated your tasks.json build task to use the clang++ argument --`std=c++17`. By default, clang++ uses the C++98 standard, which doesn't support the initialization used in `helloworld.cpp`. Make sure to replace the entire contents of your tasks.json file with the code block provided in the [Run helloworld.cpp](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_run-helloworldcpp) section."*

You will need to copy-paste this exact code and replace the code in the `tasks.json` folder:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
      "args": [
        "-std=c++17",
        "-stdlib=libc++",
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
  ]
}
```

To find the `tasks.json` folder, go to your program-file, do `Command` + `Shift` + `.` to find hidden files > `.vscode` > `tasks.json` > replace all the code in the file with the one I provided. It updates the C++ compiler to use a more updated version of C++ which recognizes the syntax.