# Changing version of C++ on visual studio code mac previous answers don't seem to work

Tags: c++, c++17, c++98

Hello have just started programming c++ but realized by default version of C++ is 98 on my vscode. I have tried changing the cpp Standard field to c++17 also went into tasks.json to change the flag in args however am very confused why my version is still c++98?

Comment: See similar issue: [How to change c++ version being used by vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66680147/how-to-change-c-version-being-used-by-vscode)

Comment: Mac clang defaults to c++98 (no idea why) there's nothing you can do to change that. What have you changed in `tasks.json`? How are you building your code? Please show a [mre]