# Result of string in conditional statement in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
if( condition && "Text in double quotes")
    {
    do this;
    }
else
    {
    do that;
    }
```

Saw this code in a program, in which case would the conditional expression in the IF-statement return *true* and in which case would it return *false*?

Comment: non null string is always true, but false in `&&` condition always makes whole statement false

Comment: I've seen similar code to 'add comments' to asserts, like this: `assert(condition && "Message");`. The string doesn't affect the result, but you will probably get the entire line with the message printed out if the assertion occurs.

Comment: See [How does C++ handle &&? (Short-circuit evaluation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66680147/how-to-change-c-version-being-used-by-vscode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`false && "Literally anything"` is always `false`.
The primary expression is `false`, `operator &&` is a [logical operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) (unless it was overloaded), so it will [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).
This is because `false && E` (where E is an [expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions)) is known to always evaluate to `false`. Therefore `E` doesn't need to be evaluated at all.
So if `E` was a function call with side effects: the side effects won't occur since the function is never called.

Example:

```cpp
int main() { return false && "anything"; } // returns 0
```

Live on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:31,endLineNumber:2,positionColumn:31,positionLineNumber:2,selectionStartColumn:31,selectionStartLineNumber:2,startColumn:31,startLineNumber:2),source:%27int+main()+%7B%0A++++return+false+%26%26+%22anything%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1500,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wunreachable-code+-O%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+15.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)