# VSCode IntelliSense thinks we're in C++11 against all configuration (as evidenced by `__cplusplus` macro)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Small C++ project using CMake, set to c++20, compiles fine using `<string_view>`.

- host OS: Windows 10, remote OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- VSCode versions: VSCode 1.71.2, C/C++ extension 1.12.4, CMake Tools 1.12.27
- compiler: clang 15 as installed by `apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh`

But VSCode IntelliSense insists that `std::string_view` is undefined:

[image]

If I `F12` on `#include <string_view>` I go to `/usr/include/c++/9/string_view` where I see that it thinks the built-in preprocessor macro `__cplusplus` is set to c++11:

[image]

It is getting its configuration from CMake Tools as seen by the following message in the "C/C++ Configuration Warnings" output window:

> `[10/3/2022, 9:57:47 PM] For C++ source files, the cppStandard was changed from "c++23" to "c++20" based on compiler args and querying compilerPath: "/usr/bin/clang"`

(I had set the VSCode IntelliSense Configuration "C++ standard" to "c++23" while my CMake project was still saying "c++20".)

My `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64",
            "includePath": [],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Why is the built-in `__cplusplus` macro wrong for whatever it is that IntelliSense is doing?

The IntelliSense engine is "default":

[image]

I installed the extension `clangd`--Clang's own language server--and disabled the built-in IntellSense (`clangd` warned of a conflict there, which would be expected).  This doesn't work either, but *now* `__cplusplus` is set to c++14--no other change to any settings were made.

[image]

I did try the solution suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68401689/751579) to [How to change C++ version being used by VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66680147/how-to-change-c-version-being-used-by-vscode) which is to set the language in the C/C++ extension settings.  As is demonstrated by the `c_cpp_properties.json` file included--they are the "cStandard" and "cppStandard" properties. And the question *also* shows that those properties aren't *used in this case* because I'm using the setting where IntelliSense asks the build system--CMake Tools in this case--for the proper settings: that is shown by the actual message given by CMake Tools.

Comment: @273K the closure of this question has been disputed in [a revision](/revisions/73941460/3) and [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420668) if you'd like to follow up.

Comment: That question is about setting C++ version for the extension ms-vscode.cpptools that is vscode Intellisense. There is nothing about compilation.

Comment: @HenryEcker This question is a duplicate of the well answered question.

Comment: @273K I appreciate your taking a second look. To be clear, I wasn't disagreeing with your action (I know almost nothing about this specific topic). I was just bringing it to your attention in case you were interested in following up with the OP here.

Comment: @273K - Oh, and _one more thing.  Here is the _actual other question_: "I printed ..cplusplus and found out that my files are executed with C++98 in VSCode. "  The question asks about _executing_ (that is, _compiling_ and executing) C++. And that _execution_ gave the wrong version.  The _question_ is _not_ about Intellisense.  And also the answer, with 16 votes, wasn't checked as "the answer" by the questioner.  In _this_ question compilation _works_.

Comment: I recommend you to uninstall the Clangd extension, it can give you more problems than that, like cryptic errors like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73115800/unknown-signal-exception-when-debugging-on-visual-studio-code) question I asked while ago. Use the Microsoft one, it's  more stable.

Comment: @OtávioAugustoSilva - well, what you say doesn't surprise me in general anyway, but I will do that as that extension didn't fix this particular problem anyway!

Comment: I see `/usr/include/c++/9`, are there any other version?

Comment: I see you've set `"configurationProvider"` in your cpp-tools config. Have you done anything in your CMake configuration to indicate the language standard to use? Ex. configuring [the `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` cache variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html) or using [`target_compile_features`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html)?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: @philipxy - thank you I get that of course, problem is Intellisense is entirely a matter of _the IDE_.  It's important to show, for purposes of this question, how screenshots of the IDE because that's really the only way to show some of what it is thinking.  (The error about `string_view` shows up in a message window -  though _not_ a terminal window - but the information about what value it thinks the macro has is only shown in a pop-up window.  AFAIK. Correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Content that isn't about how something looks should be given as text. Like error messages & code. Thanks, I'm done.

Comment: @david-fong - true, I did not give you my `CMakeLists.txt` but I _did_ give the informational message from the VSCode "CMake provider" which works off of it, using CMake itself to interpret it, and _that_ informed us that the compiler told it it was set to use `C++20`.  Thanks!

Comment: for me, it was the `"configurationProvider"` key-value pair in `settings.json`. i got rid of the problem by deleting that line entirely.

Comment: If vscode intellisense still cannot detect the standard higher than C++14. Try to search in command palette (ctrl+p or ctrl+shift+p) with `C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)`. Then check the `C++ standard` in this UI. I found it was set to `C++14` while `ms-vscode.cpptools` was set to `C++20`.

Comment: I was able to fix this on Windows with MSVC/cl.exe by adding `/Zc:__cplusplus` to the compiler arguments.

Comment: you need to show a [mre], which I've already asked about several months ago. For what it's worth, I just wrote [what I think is a better answer to the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76610269/11107541).