# How can I change the C++ standard used by the Code Runner extension for VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw, mingw-w64, vscode-code-runner

I'm trying to use C++20 in VS Code with [the Code Runner extension](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner), which allows me to run code using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>.

I have installed MinGW64 through the MSYS2 installer.
My compiler version is 12.0.2.

- In my c_cpp_properties.json file, I have set `cppStandard` to `c++20`.
- For good measure, in my settings.json file, I added `"C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++20"`.
- In my tasks.json file, I have added `"-std=c++20"` to the `args` field.

When I type `__cplusplus` in my C++ file and hover my mouse over it, the hover info says "`# define __cplusplus 202002L`".

But the Code Runner extension is still not using C++20. Why? How can I make it use C++20?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to edit the [`code-runner.executorMap`](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner#configuration) setting to add the C++ standard selection flag there. Perhaps something like this:

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
  "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++20 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
}
```

You're seeing "`# define __cplusplus 202002L`" in your hover info because that's controlled by the [vscode-cpptools](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools) extension- a separate extension from the Code Runner extension, which reads your c_cpp_properties-related settings.

tasks.json is a VS Code feature, which I assume you're using to define a build task. I think there's usually not much reason to have both a build task in the tasks.json as well as usage of Code Runner, because Code Runner will handle building and running (but it's really only good for extremely simple use-cases).

As far as I know, the Code Runner extension doesn't care about your tasks.json tasks, or your vscode-cpptools settings.

Loosely related issue ticket: [Update default settings of code-runner.executorMap to support c++11 or higher versions #397](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/397).