Issues with Eigen Library Setup in VS Code for C++ Projects
I am encountering difficulties in including the Eigen library in my C++ project using Visual Studio Code and MinGW. Despite following multiple tutorials, I am still receiving the error: Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory. Below are the steps I have taken so far:

Downloaded the Eigen zip file from the TuxFamily website.
Extracted the contents into a folder named toolBox on my C: drive.
Created a basic template test code file in VS Code..
Included the eigen file directory in 'tasks.json' (Refer Image: https://i.sstatic.net/mOZ4eVDs.png)
Included the eigne file directory in 'c_cpp_properties.json' (Refer Image: https://i.sstatic.net/ylQ1MX0w.png)

Despite these configurations, my code still fails to compile with the error: Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory. I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

Please don't post images of text files. Post text as text.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Why beginners try to use VS code? It is most beginner unfriendly IDE (at least for C++).

does c:\toolbox\eigen-3.4.0\Eigen\Dense exist?

You should have installed this package: https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-eigen3?repo=ucrt64 remember that the VSCode official MinGW Instructions told you to use msys2 to install MinGW so if you followed the recommended guide you should have pacman and should be using the ucrt MinGW.

@AlanBirtles Yes, I have that directory

It should be a file, not a directory

To rephrase @AlanBirtles 's question: did you unpack it so that C:\toolbox\eigen-3.4.0\Eigen exists as a directory (with a file Dense in it) or did you unpack the ZIP file so that it actually created C:\toolbox\eigen-3.4.0\eigen-3.4.0\Eigen as a directory instead?

@AlanBirtles I have Dense file along with all other files inside the C:\toolBox\eigen-3.4.0\Eigen

My next guess then (still without being able to see a [mre] of all your config files) is that you're not actually using the task defined in your tasks.json and are using code runner instead

@AlanBirtles Yes, I am using code runner extension, will it not work if I use this extension?

it might work but that makes your tasks.json irrelevant, you'll need to look up the code runner documentation for how to set compiler flags. You really shouldn't be using either tasks.json or code runner for compiling non-trivial c++ programs, you need to invest in a build system like cmake, make, meson etc.

for code runner: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75892388/11107541. for cmake tools: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77079021/11107541
